# Dismiss dialog builder before moving fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have an `AlertDialog.Builder` in fragment1 and if i don't click on it (to remove it) it stays even when another fragment is called.
How can i dismiss it? there is no dismiss method!

Comment: *there is no dismiss method!*, where?

Comment: There's dialogInterface.dismiss() method

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlertDialog.Builder` is used to build an actual dialog using [AlertDialog.Builder.html#show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show()). You should store the output from this method in a variable and use it to dismiss the dialog later if needs be:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
...
dialog.dismiss(); //or dialog.cancel() which will also call your OnCancelListener
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DialogFragment for this purpose and override `onCreateDialog(Bundle)` method instead of using regular fragment. And DialogFragment has `dismiss()` method, so you can dismiss it whenever you want. 
For more details see [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).